# How to configure SOLR to index by preserving the original case, but query by ignoring case

Tags: solr

Here is my use case :

In my app, there is a field to enter **person name**. And I want to make this **person name** auto suggest through SOLR.

Let me explain in example, let say previously user have entered below values :

1. Wong Yek Hon
2. wong yek hon
3. WONG YEK HON

And now, when user enter "wong", my app suppose to list out all the 3 options as auto-suggest. Similarly, when user enter "WONG", my app suppose to list out all the 3 options also.

Here is how I configured the SOLR schema.xml :

```
<fieldType name="text_sentence_auto" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

With this configuration, I able to index the name by preserving the original case, but the query is always case sensitive, meanings when user enter "wong", the SOLR only return "wong yek hon". Please advise how to make the query NOT case sensitive?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To do query in case insensitive mode in Solr. You can keep both **analyser and query** as `<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>`.

**LowerCaseFilterFactory** is only filter factory. It doesn't affect on your storing data. It preserve case sensitivity as it is in index documents..

Configure for Solr schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text_sentence_auto" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```